# Load EF Entity using KeyID1, KeyID2, KeyID3

Tags: entity-framework, linq

```
var Subjects = db.Subjects.ToList();
var SubjectIDs = (from a in Subjects select a.ID).ToArray();

// Unable to write this part
var Students = db.Students.Where(c = > c.SubjectID == FundIDs).ToList();
```

Actually I am looking for students having SubjectIDs.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what you're after - you want to find students with an id in SubjectIDs?

If so, try Contains - in Linq - where SubjectIDs.Contains(c.ID)
As Lambda it would look something like .Where(c => SubjectIDs.Contains(c.ID))

HTH,

Adam.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Adam Benson

The query I was looking for

```
   var Students = db.Students.Where(c = > SubjectIDs.Contains(c.SubjectID)).ToList();
```